# Column Positioning in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following three sections of content:

- A - main content of page
- B - very important content (must be visible without scrolling)
- C - less important content.

The layout I have is like so:

```
-----
|A|B|
|A|C|
-----
```

But when the viewport is narrower it turns to:

```
---
|A|
|B|
|C|
---
```

with B no longer on screen.

I've managed to make it do:

```
---
|B|
|C|    
|A|
---
```

But what I really want is:

```
---
|B|
|A|
|C|
---
```

Does anyone know any way of managing this using bootstrap?

Comment: Where is the second A gone? Normally it would turn from your first version into A|B|A|C? Or are there two blocks AA and BC?

Comment: render b first with float right and A with float left twice and c with float left again

Comment: How complex is the content of B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cool little question, I must say. You can solve it by using float:right; on column B and C to force the responsive behaviour.

You can find an example here: http://codepen.io/belens/pen/uvdkp

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-b col-sm-6">B</div>
    <div class="col-a col-sm-6">A</div> 
    <div class="col-c col-sm-6">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[class*="col"] {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.col-a {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: SteelBlue;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-c, .col-b {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

In my example the B column will get indexed first, however. I assumed you want B first.

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect and really elegant as well!